# How to Convert the rgba data to base64 to show image

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, html5-canvas

i am using canvas tag  in this  to disply some Rect i have used this code

```
var canvas=document.getElementById("myCanvas");

     if (canvas.getContext) {
         var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
         ctx.fillStyle="red";
         ctx.fillRect(0,0,50,50);

         var  newRGBA=new Array();

     // and can't do the ctx.ToDataUrl("image/png") bc  in andriod 2.2 this not  supported 
         // here canvas  returns me the Array RGBA
     newRGBA= ctx.getImageData(0,0,50,50);
}
```

My query is how to bind this data to image.src=RGBAdata ;
I have tried  this

```
 document.getElementById("imgid").src="data:image/png;base64," +  btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(this,newRGBA.data))+" ";
```

Comment: What this has to do with Android?

Comment: This is not as simple as you think, all you have now is an array of the pixels of an image but this by itself is not any kind of valid image format, like PNG or BMP, which the browser expects on the img tag.

Yes, it's possible to do what you want to but it would require you to take the time to learn the file spec for an image format, the easiest would probably be the BMP one. And then work on a binary string to dinamically build your image file, then convert it to base64.

Comment: @Ruuhkis thank you  for you are quick response,  but  when i use the the ToDataUrl("image/png") it will returns me the Data:, in emulator 2.2v , in browser it is working fine it gives all base64 data and if i use 4.0v then it will returns  all base64 data in emulator .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

toDataURL is not implememented in android 2.x so i have done some workaround involves creating a BMP base64 data and png base64 from canvas.

reference here 
    1 to make  [pngbase64](http://todataurl-png-js.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/todataurl.js) from canvas.
    2 to make  [BMP base64](http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/canvas2image/canvas2image.js) from canvas.

```
//code here for pngbase64 from canvas:

Number.prototype.toUInt = function () { return this < 0 ? this + 4294967296 : this; };
Number.prototype.bytes32 = function () { return [(this >>> 24) & 0xff, (this >>> 16) & 0xff, (this >>> 8) & 0xff, this & 0xff]; };
Number.prototype.bytes32sw = function () { return [this & 0xff, (this >>> 8) & 0xff, (this >>> 16) & 0xff, (this >>> 24) & 0xff]; };
Number.prototype.bytes16 = function () { return [(this >>> 8) & 0xff, this & 0xff]; };
Number.prototype.bytes16sw = function () { return [this & 0xff, (this >>> 8) & 0xff]; };

Array.prototype.adler32 = function (start, len) {
    switch (arguments.length) { case 0: start = 0; case 1: len = this.length - start; }
    var a = 1, b = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        a = (a + this[start + i]) % 65521; b = (b + a) % 65521;
    }
    return ((b << 16) | a).toUInt();
};

Array.prototype.crc32 = function (start, len) {
    switch (arguments.length) { case 0: start = 0; case 1: len = this.length - start; }
    var table = arguments.callee.crctable;
    if (!table) {
        table = [];
        var c;
        for (var n = 0; n < 256; n++) {
            c = n;
            for (var k = 0; k < 8; k++)
                c = c & 1 ? 0xedb88320 ^ (c >>> 1) : c >>> 1;
            table[n] = c.toUInt();
        }
        arguments.callee.crctable = table;
    }
    var c = 0xffffffff;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)
        c = table[(c ^ this[start + i]) & 0xff] ^ (c >>> 8);

    return (c ^ 0xffffffff).toUInt();
};


var createPNG = function (canvasid) {
var imageData = Array.prototype.slice.call(canvasid.getContext("2d").getImageData(0, 0, canvasid.width, canvasid.height).data);
var w = canvasid.width;
var h = canvasid.height;
var stream = [
                   0x89, 0x50, 0x4e, 0x47, 0x0d, 0x0a, 0x1a, 0x0a,
                   0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0d, 0x49, 0x48, 0x44, 0x52
           ];
Array.prototype.push.apply(stream, w.bytes32());
Array.prototype.push.apply(stream, h.bytes32());
stream.push(0x08, 0x06, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00);
Array.prototype.push.apply(stream, stream.crc32(12, 17).bytes32());
var len = h * (w * 4 + 1);
for (var y = 0; y < h; y++)
   imageData.splice(y * (w * 4 + 1), 0, 0);
var blocks = Math.ceil(len / 32768);
Array.prototype.push.apply(stream, (len + 5 * blocks + 6).bytes32());
var crcStart = stream.length;
var crcLen = (len + 5 * blocks + 6 + 4);
stream.push(0x49, 0x44, 0x41, 0x54, 0x78, 0x01);
for (var i = 0; i < blocks; i++) {
   var blockLen = Math.min(32768, len - (i * 32768));
   stream.push(i == (blocks - 1) ? 0x01 : 0x00);
   Array.prototype.push.apply(stream, blockLen.bytes16sw());
   Array.prototype.push.apply(stream, (~blockLen).bytes16sw());
   var id = imageData.slice(i * 32768, i * 32768 + blockLen);
   Array.prototype.push.apply(stream, id);
}
Array.prototype.push.apply(stream, imageData.adler32().bytes32());
Array.prototype.push.apply(stream, stream.crc32(crcStart, crcLen).bytes32());

stream.push(0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x49, 0x45, 0x4e, 0x44);
Array.prototype.push.apply(stream, stream.crc32(stream.length - 4, 4).bytes32());
return  "data:image/png;base64," + btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, stream));
};



 //code here for bmpbase64 from canvas:
var encodeData = function(data) {
    var strData = "";
    if (typeof data == "string") {
        strData = data;
    } else {
        var aData = data;
        for (var i=0;i<aData.length;i++) {
            strData += String.fromCharCode(aData[i]);
        }
    }
    return btoa(strData);
}

// creates a base64 encoded string containing BMP data
// takes an imagedata object as argument
var createBMP = function(oData) {
    var aHeader = [];

    var iWidth = oData.width;
    var iHeight = oData.height;

    aHeader.push(0x42); // magic 1
    aHeader.push(0x4D); 

    var iFileSize = iWidth*iHeight*3 + 54; // total header size = 54 bytes
    aHeader.push(iFileSize % 256); iFileSize = Math.floor(iFileSize / 256);
    aHeader.push(iFileSize % 256); iFileSize = Math.floor(iFileSize / 256);
    aHeader.push(iFileSize % 256); iFileSize = Math.floor(iFileSize / 256);
    aHeader.push(iFileSize % 256);

    aHeader.push(0); // reserved
    aHeader.push(0);
    aHeader.push(0); // reserved
    aHeader.push(0);

    aHeader.push(54); // dataoffset
    aHeader.push(0);
    aHeader.push(0);
    aHeader.push(0);

    var aInfoHeader = [];
    aInfoHeader.push(40); // info header size
    aInfoHeader.push(0);
    aInfoHeader.push(0);
    aInfoHeader.push(0);

    var iImageWidth = iWidth;
    aInfoHeader.push(iImageWidth % 256); iImageWidth = Math.floor(iImageWidth / 256);
    aInfoHeader.push(iImageWidth % 256); iImageWidth = Math.floor(iImageWidth / 256);
    aInfoHeader.push(iImageWidth % 256); iImageWidth = Math.floor(iImageWidth / 256);
    aInfoHeader.push(iImageWidth % 256);

    var iImageHeight = iHeight;
    aInfoHeader.push(iImageHeight % 256); iImageHeight = Math.floor(iImageHeight / 256);
    aInfoHeader.push(iImageHeight % 256); iImageHeight = Math.floor(iImageHeight / 256);
    aInfoHeader.push(iImageHeight % 256); iImageHeight = Math.floor(iImageHeight / 256);
    aInfoHeader.push(iImageHeight % 256);

    aInfoHeader.push(1); // num of planes
    aInfoHeader.push(0);

    aInfoHeader.push(24); // num of bits per pixel
    aInfoHeader.push(0);

    aInfoHeader.push(0); // compression = none
    aInfoHeader.push(0);
    aInfoHeader.push(0);
    aInfoHeader.push(0);

    var iDataSize = iWidth*iHeight*3; 
    aInfoHeader.push(iDataSize % 256); iDataSize = Math.floor(iDataSize / 256);
    aInfoHeader.push(iDataSize % 256); iDataSize = Math.floor(iDataSize / 256);
    aInfoHeader.push(iDataSize % 256); iDataSize = Math.floor(iDataSize / 256);
    aInfoHeader.push(iDataSize % 256); 

    for (var i=0;i<16;i++) {
        aInfoHeader.push(0);    // these bytes not used
    }

    var iPadding = (4 - ((iWidth * 3) % 4)) % 4;

    var aImgData = oData.data;

    var strPixelData = "";
    var y = iHeight;
    do {
        var iOffsetY = iWidth*(y-1)*4;
        var strPixelRow = "";
        for (var x=0;x<iWidth;x++) {
            var iOffsetX = 4*x;

            strPixelRow += String.fromCharCode(aImgData[iOffsetY+iOffsetX+2]);
            strPixelRow += String.fromCharCode(aImgData[iOffsetY+iOffsetX+1]);
            strPixelRow += String.fromCharCode(aImgData[iOffsetY+iOffsetX]);
        }
        for (var c=0;c<iPadding;c++) {
            strPixelRow += String.fromCharCode(0);
        }
        strPixelData += strPixelRow;
    } while (--y);

    var strEncoded = encodeData(aHeader.concat(aInfoHeader)) + encodeData(strPixelData);

    return "data:image/bmp;base64,"+strEncoded;
}


 // BMPbase64  usage onload 
     var canvasbmp = document.getElementById("canvasbmp");
     var ctxbmp = canvasbmp.getContext("2d");
         ctxbmp.fillStyle="#FF0000";//fill color in to canvas  here..
        ctxbmp.fillRect(0,0,170,100);
     var imagedata= ctxbmp.getImageData(0, 0, canvasbmp.width, canvasbmp.height);
     var bmpbase64data=createBMP(imagedata);//it will  returns me the bmpbase64 data.


     document.getElementById("testimagebmp").src =bmpbase64data;


 // pngbase64  usage onload 

var canvaspng = document.getElementById("canvaspng");
         var ctxpng = canvaspng.getContext("2d");
             ctxpng.fillStyle="#FF0000";//fill color in to canvas  here..
            ctxpng.fillRect(0,0,170,100);
         var imagedata= ctxpng.getImageData(0, 0, canvaspng .width, canvaspng.height);
         var pngbase64data= createPNG(imagedata);//it will  returns me the pngbase64 data.
 document.getElementById("testimagepng").src =pngbase64data;

//html code here
   <canvas id="canvasbmp" width="200" height="100" style="border:2px solid #c3c3c3;"></canvas>
   <canvas id="canvaspng" width="200" height="100" style="border:2px solid #c3c3c3;"></canvas>

  <img id="testimagebmp"  width="200" height="100" style="border:2px solid #c3c3c3;" />
  <img id="testimagepng"  width="200" height="100" style="border:2px solid #c3c3c3;" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Canvas has a method called `toDataURL`, which is what you're after. If does doesn't work from localhost, or from an emulator, you might experience cross-domain issues, which is currently only support by Chrome (check support for your browser here: http://maplarge.com/CrossOriginImageTest.html)

[Here's a good example.](http://introducinghtml5.com/examples/ch05/todataurl.html)